# how to create custom parameters on azure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am building an azure relase pipeline, When i press 'create release', I am brought to the following screen in which i can give input. How can i add in my own custom field, to define a new parameter?

For clarification, I am asking how to do those on a classic release pipeline, NOT a new yaml pipeline.

Here is how i would create parameters on a yaml pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: aspName
  displayName: 'App service plan name'
  type: string
  default: mydefaule
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom Runtime Paramters is only supported by **Yaml Pipeline**.

Here is a doc about [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/parameters?view=azure-devops)

In the release pipeline, I am afraid that there is no  exactly the same feature.

**Similar feature：** You could set the release variable as **Settable at release time**.

[image]

Then when you run the release pipeline, you could set the variable value.

[image]

**Note:** This is Release Pipeline variable instead of Parameters. If you still want to get exactly the same function（Runtime parameters） as in the yaml pipeline, I suggest that you could vote the following Suggestion Ticket in Our UserVoice site: [Runtime parameters with Release pipelines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/runtime-parameters-with-release-pipelines/1104430).

Comment: This is almost exaclty what I want - Would there be a way to configure a set of acceptable values, and have this as a drop down list rathe than a text box?

Comment: I fully understand your requirement.  But there is no feature to completely realize it in release pipeline for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set it in the variable tab of the pipeline, and ensure its ticked as "settable at queue time"

you then reference it by using "$(variableName)" within the stage you wish to use it in

[i cant embed images yet, link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03KBw.png)

Answer (score 2):

That's an easy thing. You have to mark which release variables are settable (right column in variables tab).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxmDH.png